# xpath regex doesn't search tail in lxml.etree

Tags: python, regex, xpath, lxml

I'm working with `lxml.etree` and I'm trying to allow users to search a docbook for text.  When a user provides the search text, I use the [exslt](http://exslt.org/regular-expressions) `match` function to find the text within the docbook.  The match works just fine if the text shows up within the `element.text` but not if the text is in `element.tail`.

Here's an example:

```
>>> # XML as lxml.etree element
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring('''
...   <root>
...     <foo>Sample text
...       <bar>and more sample text</bar> and important text.
...     </foo>
...   </root>
... ''')
>>>
>>> # User provides search text    
>>> search_term = 'important'
>>>
>>> # Find nodes with matching text
>>> matches = root.xpath('//*[re:match(text(), $search, "i")]', search=search_term, namespaces={'re':'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'})
>>> print(matches)
[]
>>>
>>> # But I know it's there...
>>> bar = root.xpath('//bar')[0]
>>> print(bar.tail)
 and important text.
```

I'm confused because the `text()` function by itself returns all the text – including the `tail`:

```
>>> # text() results
>>> text = root.xpath('//child1/text()')
>>> print(text)
['Sample text',' and important text']
```

How come the `tail` isn't being included when I use the `match` function?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you are looking for, but you may find it useful to try string() instead of text() in your xpath expression.

Comment: @mehtunguh `string()` doesn't work in this instance.  While it does find the term "important" it returns the `<root>` and `<foo>` elements which have the same portion of text where the match was made... It would be a new problem to figure out how to determine which text was already matched...

Answer (score 2):

> How come the tail isn't being included when I use the match function?

That's  because in xpath 1.0, when given a node-set, `match()` function (or any other string function such as `contains()`, `starts-with()`, etc.) only take into account the first node.

Instead of what you did, you can use `//text()` and apply regex match filter on individual text nodes, and then return the text node's parent element, like so :

```
xpath = '//text()[re:match(., $search, "i")]/parent::*'
matches = root.xpath(xpath, search=search_term, namespaces={'re':'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'})
```